# A question on existence of gradient vector field on manifold with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a compact manifold with smooth boundary $\partial M$. Does $M$ admit a gradient vector field $\nabla u$, which has no zeros, i.e. $\nabla u(x)\neq 0$, $\forall x\in M\cup\partial M$?

Thanks so much.

Comment: No, generally not.  For example, all vector fields on  $0$-manifolds are zero everywhere.  Vector fields on even dimensional spheres always have zeros, etc.  Are you familiar with the relationship between vector fields and the Euler characteristic?  Perhaps look in an introductory manifold theory book, like Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Off the top of my head the only examples of what you are looking for would be manifolds of the form $I \times M$, and the vector field would be the gradient of the projection map $I \times M \to I$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla u$ when $x\in \partial M$? (In particular, on the boundary, do you allow $\nabla u$ to point "out" from the manifold? If so, then @RyanBudney's comment needs amending since you have examples like $\mathbb{S}^2$ with three open discs removed.)

Comment: I think you are going in the direction of Morse theory on manifolds with boundary (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3066 ). Note that in that manuscript, the Morse functions considered are required to more-or-less have boundary-tangent gradients (see Definition 1.4). Hence my previous comment.

Comment: Yuan, consider crossposting this question to math.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, I was a little confused by your language.  I would phrase your question by saying "$M$ is a manifold with non-empty boundary".  At least to me, "manifold with boundary" is a class of manifold that includes manifolds without boundary.  For manifolds with boundary are you considering the gradient just to be a vector field on the manifold $M$?  Another natural thing to do would be to consider the gradient as indexed by the strata of $M$, i.e. there is also the gradient on $\partial M$, etc. These two versions of the question would have quite different answers.